# Database access in Bash Shell scripting

Tags: sql, linux, bash, shell, unix

I am new to shell scripting world.

I wrote a bash shell script.

Name of the script is new.sh

```
Select T1.date as dateFact,
T2.idmfg as idMfg,
T1.id as userId,
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN 
Table2 T2
ON 
T1.id=T2.id 
WHERE 
T1.date ='${Date}'
T2.idmfg='${idMfg}';
```

While running new.sh, I want to enter `Date` and `idMfg` manually. E.g.

```
sh new.sh -d 2013-03-20 -i 201
```

Where, `Date` is `2013-03-20` and `idMfg` is `201`.

How can I do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

Date="$1"
idMfg="$2"

mysql<<EOF
SELECT T1.date AS dateFact, T2.idmfg AS idMfg, T1.id AS userId
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2
ON T1.id=T2.id 
WHERE T1.date = "${Date}", T2.idmfg = "${idMfg}";
EOF
```

Usage :

```
./new.sh 2013-03-20 201
```

To go further if you want named switches, see the tutorial: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial Examples: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035

Comment: How can I put it inside case e.g.

case $Option in 
d) date="${date}"
i) idmfg="${idMfg}"
esac;


so I can run as: new.sh -d 2013-03-20 -i 201

Comment: Use the getopts tutorial mentioned in the answer

Comment: @tink : MySQL is just an example ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 new.sh 2013-03-20 201
```

Inside the script the first (date) param is $1, the second $2.